# Minicart 2.1 Minicart doesn't show products added to the cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1, mini-cart, knockoutjs

I'm working on a Magento 2.1 shop with a custom theme. When I use the blank theme, everything works just fine. The moment I enable my own theme, but without overwriting the minicart templates I have the following problem.

The item count in the minicart gets updated but overview of products in your cart is not there. Also the "Go to checkout"-"button and the "Close"-button of the minicart are not working anymore. This is what my console logs.

```
Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:getCartParam('items'),as:'item'} }"
Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:getCartParam('items'),as:'item'} }"
Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
Cannot read property 'configurable' of undefined
```

It might be relevant to note that I moved the minicart in my default.xml file to another location, not sure if relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Have you overridden or extended your `minicart.js` script?

2.1 introduced some changes to these files to resolve previous issues with the minicart values not updating on page load. Assuming you have overridden this file or extended some of its functions, you'll have to bring it in line with the changes that were introduced with 2.1.

Here's the commit with the relevant changes:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/eec3cf17bc5deae71c83c797d1339de46cf6905f
Namely, `cart()` was replaced with call to new function `getCartParam()`.

Hope this helps resolve your issue!

Answer (score 1):

Its a current bug of Magento 2.1.0. Feel free to create a new issue with your matter at GitHub: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by setting up file permissions and recompiling:

```
chown my-user:www-data -R .    
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

then purged everything that could be purged:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed to me when I upgrade my PHP version **from 7.0.9 to 7.0.15**.

I use this [container Docker.](https://hub.docker.com/r/rafaelcgstz/magento2/)

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same issue in Magento 2.1.7 and other versions. That is not a permission issue, not any type of js issue. this issue comes from when you set up a new theme in Magento 2 and when you add a product add to cart then showing this type

[image]

First of all Please check your default mini cart working and then check theme mini cart. if the mini cart is not working then remove your default file.

**path:-** `app/design/frontend/[theme-name]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml`

And then

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then check its working Now.